# unable to disable swap after reboot

Tags: 16.04, boot, mount, swap

## Question

**why is my swap partition being used after reboot?**

## Context

My system has two swap areas in Linux Ubuntu:

```
sudo swapon --show
NAME                 TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/nvme0n1p7       partition 977M   0B   -2
/media/EXT4/swapfile file        4G   0B   -3
```

I disabled swap partition:

```
sudo swapon --show
NAME                 TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/media/EXT4/swapfile file        4G   0B   -3
```

and edited /etc/fstab:

```
UUID=8a098c42-9f6a-4f04-8dac-87298f1f460d /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=CC3B-B509  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p7 during installation
# UUID=0379c3e0-faa9-4bd8-a7ce-4bc1d2d1d9a2 none            swap    sw              0       0

# 4TB HDD, linux partition
UUID="847df9cc-ba11-469f-a36e-ac4228c005f8" /media/EXT4 ext4 user,errors=remount-ro,auto,exec,rw
# 4TB HDD, windows partition
UUID="2A2506563E8741C6" /media/NTFS ntfs user,errors=remount-ro,auto,exec,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000

/media/EXT4/swapfile none swap sw 0 0
```

## Problem

after reboot the partition is used as swap area:

```
sudo swapon --show
NAME                 TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/nvme0n1p7       partition 977M   0B   -2
/media/EXT4/swapfile file        4G   0B   -3
```

## Further information

Here is the information of linux-swap:

[image: linux-swap information]

it shows the UUID in fstab is commented out for swap partition.

These are the flags for linux-swap: (none are used)

[image]

[I do not have Autofs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23549055/10636865) installed on my system.

Comment: Don't you have a second fstab-line regarding the swap-file? Please show us the complete output of `cat /etc/fstab`.

Comment: yes, of course I have a couple of mounting points. I added the complete fstab, it shouldn't be relevant, though. There's also a `/etc/fstab.bak` which has the linux-swap.

Comment: I had to delete the swap partition with fstab to disable swap after reboot. Just removing it from fstab didn't work on Ubuntu 16.04.6

Comment: Well... your fstab still has this definition in there: `/media/EXT4/swapfile none swap sw 0 0` ... suggesting that you *didn't* actually disable it.

Comment: @ThomasWard my system has two swap areas. The intention is to use the one on `/media/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you have indeed disabled that swap partition in your `/etc/fstab` file.

I would ,however, suggest one more step.

1. Please, first turn all swap off `swapoff -a`. Then type in the terminal:

   `sudo nano /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`

Check if the UUID for disabled swap is in the file.

If yes, please comment it out by adding `#` before that line. Save the file and exit.

2. Recreate the boot images:

   `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all`
3. Update GRUB:

   `sudo update-grub`

Then, please reboot and see if this works.

You might as well want to delete your swap partition and extend your system partition after that to utilize the unused space.

Comment: this seems to be the correct answer. I'll try this when I have some time.

Comment: I wasn't able to recreate the initial context due to time difference between question / answer. I accept it as answer.

Answer (score 4):

As well as @Raffa's suggestion, you may also need to disable the automatic activation at boot of detected swap space in systemd, to do this find out the responsible .swap unit by running:

```
sudo systemctl --type swap
```

This should then list out the current swap units in the following format (In my case the swap unit name was `dev-sda7.swap`):

```
  UNIT          LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
  dev-sda7.swap loaded active active Swap Partition

  LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
  ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
  SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.
```

Disable this swap unit from starting at boot by masking it:

```
sudo systemctl mask dev-sda7.swap
```

Answer (score 1):

@PJConnol,

Thanks, you were perfect! This solve it for me.

First disable an entry for swap in `/etc/fstab:`

Execute

```
# Be careful, if possible reboot before then execute next steps
swapoff -a 

sudo systemctl --type swap

 UNIT          LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
 dev-sda7.swap loaded active active Swap Partition

 LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
 ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
 SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.
```

then disable it:

```
sudo systemctl mask dev-sda7.swap
```

then reboot and verify

```
free -m
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
 Mem:           7933        1560        5011           3        1361        6130
 Swap:             0           0           0
```